# Bash Scripting : Printing column data in the same row

Tags: bash, sed, scripting, echo

I have written a bash script to calculate the size of a `PostgreSQL` database and print the output along with the date when the script was executed in a text file. The script code is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
date +"%d:%m" >> dbdata.growth
psql -h 192.168.2.173 -U postgres -c "select pg_database_size('ddb'); "  | sed -n    
'3,3p' | numfmt --to=iec >>dbdata.growth
psql -h 192.168.2.173 -U postgres -c "select pg_database_size('dpkidb'); "  | sed  
-n '3,3p' | numfmt --to=iec >>dbdata.growth
```

The script produces the following output in the format as shown below

```
26:03
         134G
         4.4M
26:03
         134G
         4.4M
```

The issue for me is that I want all the three columns in the same row. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace all output lines, such as:

```
date +"%d:%m" >> dbdata.growth
```

with lines such as:

```
date +"%d:%m" | tr -d $'\n' >> dbdata.growth
```

This uses `tr` to delete newline characters before they are put in the output file.

`tr` is a translate or delete utility.  In this case, the use of the `-d` option tells it to delete.  The character that we ask it to delete is the newline character, expressed as `$'\n'`.

Comment: Do you really need the `$`?

Answer (score 2):

The solution would be to use subshells:

```
#!/bin/bash
var1=$(date +"%d:%m")
var2=$(psql -h 192.168.2.173 -U postgres -c "select pg_database_size('ddb'); "  | sed -n '3,3p' | numfmt --to=iec)
var3=$(psql -h 192.168.2.173 -U postgres -c "select pg_database_size('dpkidb'); "  | sed  -n '3,3p' | numfmt --to=iec )
echo $var1 $var2 $var3 >>dbdata.growth
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
{ date +"%d:%m" >> dbdata.growth
psql -h 192.168.2.173 -U postgres -c "select pg_database_size('ddb'); "  | sed -n    
'3,3p' | numfmt --to=iec >>dbdata.growth
psql -h 192.168.2.173 -U postgres -c "select pg_database_size('dpkidb'); "  | sed  
-n '3,3p' | numfmt --to=iec >>dbdata.growth

} | ( 

#all output from your commands above piped to collector subshell below

set -f ; unset IFS ; set -- $(cat)
while [ $# -ge 3 ] ; do {
    printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n' "$1" "$2" "$3"
    shift 3 ; } ; done  
printf '%s\t' "$@"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know there are three columns, you could use paste:

```
your_script.sh | paste - - -
```